# Magento 2 : How to set images to product from a custom folder (Not to use pub/media folder) programmatically

Tags: magento2, product-images

There is a custom folder "productimages" in root path "localhost/magento/productimages". In this folder "productimages", there are lots of images. I want to save that images in products using object manager. So is there any way to do it ?

```
<?php 
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
use \Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap;
include('app/bootstrap.php');
$bootstraps = Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);
$object_Manager = $bootstraps->getObjectManager();
$fileSystem = $object_Manager->create('\Magento\Framework\Filesystem');
$mediaPath = $fileSystem->getDirectoryRead(\Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList::MEDIA)->getAbsolutePath();


$state = $object_Manager->get('Magento\Framework\App\State');
$state->setAreaCode('frontend');
$product_id = 19;
$product = $object_Manager->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($product_id);
$productRepository = $object_Manager->create('Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface');

$image =  $mediaPath.'imagiing.jpg';

$attributeImage = array('image', 'small_image', 'thumbnail');
// $productRepository->save($product);

$product->addImageToMediaGallery($image, $attributeImage, false, false);
$product->save();
```

Given code works only with the "pub/media" folder.

Any help will be appreciated...

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Please try with below code to create directory in root :

```
<?php 
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
use \Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap;
include('app/bootstrap.php');
$bootstraps = Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);
$object_Manager = $bootstraps->getObjectManager();
//$fileSystem = $object_Manager->create('\Magento\Framework\Filesystem');

$directory = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Framework\Filesystem\DirectoryList');


$mediaPath = $directory->getRoot().'productimages';


$state = $object_Manager->get('Magento\Framework\App\State');
$state->setAreaCode('frontend');
$product_id = 19;
$product = $object_Manager->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($product_id);
$productRepository = $object_Manager->create('Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface');

$image =  $mediaPath.'imagiing.jpg';

$attributeImage = array('image', 'small_image', 'thumbnail');
// $productRepository->save($product);

$product->addImageToMediaGallery($image, $attributeImage, false, false);
$product->save();
```

**hope very helpful to you**